# Fluent map (composite) primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent

I am trying to use the fluent syntax to map a primary key comprising the ID from the parent table, plus the ID from this table.  To illustrate:

```
Order                               OrderLine
-------------                       -------------
OrderID                             OrderID
OrderDate                           OrderLineID
Total                               Product
etc                                 Quantity
(OrderID is the primary key)        etc
                                    (OrderID, OrderLineID is the primary key)
```

The OrderLine class has an Order property (and therefore, no OrderID property).

```
public class Order                              public class OrderLine
{                                               {
  public int OrderID { get; set; }                public int OrderLineID { get; set; }
  public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }         public Product Product { get; set; }
  public double Total { get; set; }               public int Quantity { get; set; }
}                                                 
                                                  public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
                                                }
```

How do i identify that the OrderLine includes the ID of the Order in it's primary key?

I tried:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderLine>().HasKey(ol => new { ol.Order.OrderID, ol.OrderLineID });
```

but I get the following error:

```
The properties expression 'ol => new <>f__AnonymousType0`2(OrderID = ol.Order.OrderID, OrderLineID = ol.OrderLineID)' is not valid.
The expression should represent a property:
    C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. 
When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: 
    C#: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) New With { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.
```

As far as I can tell from the error message, I'm using the correct syntax, but it appears to indicate I need the ID property of the parent Order as a property in the OrderLine class - which seems to negate the point of having an Order property in the class in the first place.

So, do I need an explicit OrderID property in the OrderLine class (even though I already have an Order property) or is there something I'm not doing in the mapping to identify the primary key correctly?

Comment: I think you need to keep an explicit `OrderId` property in `OrderLine` class to achieve this. I think it will also be required at some point to establish the foreign key relation.

Comment: that's because Order is a navigation property. It doesn't even get mapped to the database as it it, so it can't be part of a primary key.